# How to get multiple tables from sqlite in iphone sdk

Tags: iphone

I have a sqlite and it has 4 different tables. How to get the all four tables in one view.
I had written for one table. Like that i had written for remaining four tables keeping statements. How to write for remaining 3 tables to get the information from sqlite database.

```
-(Question*)readData{
sqlite3_stmt *statement;
int rowid;

rowid=[self getRowId];

//.......................................TableName................................................. 

tempQuery=[@"SELECT * FROM 'iapp_question' WHERE case_id =" stringByAppendingString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",rowid]];



NSLog(@"%d print all data");

const char *query2=[tempQuery UTF8String];
if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(database,query2,-1,&statement,NULL)==SQLITE_OK) {
    qt=[[[Question alloc]init]autorelease];
    while (sqlite3_step(statement)==SQLITE_ROW) {
        qt.question=[NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement,2)];
    }
}
return qt;
```

}

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do all the tables have the same structure ?

Comment: No all are in different structure, and i want to get all the 4 table values in one view.